# Perhaps an application of Hardy's inequality

Tags: inequalities, integration, sobolev-spaces

> Let $f \in H_{0}^{1}(0,1)$ and $\lambda >0$ big enough. Consider $0 <\alpha < 1$ and some $k > 0$. I would like to show the following inequality
> $$
> \int_{\lambda^{-k}}^{1}|f(x)|^{2}dx \leq C\lambda^{-p}\int_{\lambda^{-k}}^{1}x^{\alpha}|f^{\prime}(x)|^{2}dx
> $$
> for some $p> 0$. Here, $C> 0$ is constant.

- I want to use the following Hardy's Inequalities:

Let $-\infty \leq a \leq b \leq \infty$, $g(x) \geq 0$,$h(x)\geq0$. Then the following statements are equivalent:
$$
\bigg(\int_{a}^{b}|Qu(x)|^{2}g(x)^{2}dx\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq C\bigg(\int_{a}^{b}|u(x)|^{2}h(x)^{2}dx\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}},
$$
$$
K = \sup_{x \in [a,b]}\bigg(\int_{a}^{x}[g(t)]^{2}dt\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg(\int_{x}^{b}[h(t)]^{-2}dt\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}} < \infty ,
$$
where $Qu(x) = \int_{x}^{b}u(s)ds$. Moreover, the best constant $C$ satisfies $K \leq C \leq 2K$.

- How $f(1) = 0$, because $f \in H_{0}^{1}(0,1)$, then
  $$
  |f(x)| = |f(1) - f(x)|= \bigg|\int_{x}^{1}f^{\prime}(s)ds\bigg|= |Qf^{\prime}(x)|.
  $$

Consider $h(x) = x^{\alpha/2}$, $g(x) =1$, $a=\lambda^{-k}$ and $b=1$.Thus, according to the inequality above, we would have to show that
$$
\sup_{x \in [\lambda^{-k},1]}\bigg(\int_{\lambda^{-k}}^{x}dt\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg(\int_{x}^{1}t^{-\alpha}dt\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}} < \infty
$$
But it is clear that the supreme of the above product is finite. My big question is:
After applying Hardy's inequality, how do I get $\lambda^{-p}$ to appear in front of the integral.

Comment: What is your "constant" $C$ allowed to depend on?

Comment: I don't know, it may be necessary

Comment: What may be necessary? Again, on **what** is your "constant" $C$ allowed to depend?

Comment: @losif Pinelis I don't know! thank you

Comment: @user253963: quantifiers are extremely important in analysis. If, for example, $C$ were to be allowed to depend on $k$, $\alpha$, $\lambda$, and $f$, then the statement is completely trivial. Probably we can infer that $C$ shouldn't depend on $f$ or $\lambda$. But should it be allowed to depend on $\alpha$ and $k$? You are the one asking the question, you should have some idea.

Comment: @WillieWong why is trivial when $C$ depend on $\lambda$?

Comment: No, I want the inequality to be $\lambda^{-p}$. The constant $C$ cannot take this term. If $C=2\lambda^{-p}$, then in the inequality I would miss the term $\lambda^{-p}$. I don't want something like that to happen.

Comment: The constant $C$ can depend on $\lambda$, but I don't want it to make the term $\lambda^{-p}$ disappear. For example, we can have $C= \lambda^{n}$, so $C\lambda^{-p}$ = $\lambda^{n-p}$, but that $n-p < 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\la\lambda\newcommand\al\alpha$If $C$ is allowed to depend on $\lambda$, just take $C=2\lambda^p$.

If $C$ is not allowed to depend on $\lambda$, take any nonzero $f\in H_{0}^{1}(0,1)$ and let $\lambda\to\infty$. Then the left-hand side of your desired inequality will go to $\int_0^1|f(x)|^2\,dx>0$ whereas its right-hand side will go to $0$, so that your desired inequality will fail to hold.

---

Let $f(x)=x(1-x)$ and let $\la\to\infty$. Then
$$\int_{\la^{-k}}^1|f(x)|^2\,dx\to\frac1{30}$$
and
$$\int_{\la^{-k}}^1 x^\al|f'(x)|^2\,dx\to h(\al):=\frac{\alpha ^2+\alpha +2}{\alpha ^3+6 \alpha ^2+11 \alpha +6},$$
so that the constant factor $L$ in the inequality
$$\int_{\la^{-k}}^1|f(x)|^2\,dx
\le L\,\int_{\la^{-k}}^1 x^\al|f'(x)|^2\,dx$$
must be $\ge\dfrac1{30h(\al)}$. So, $L$ cannot go to $0$ as $\la\to\infty$.

Comment: Why $C= 2\lambda^{p}$?

Comment: No, I want the inequality to be $\lambda^{-p}$. The constant $C$ cannot take this term. If $C=2\lambda^{-p}$, then in the inequality I would miss the term $\lambda^{-p}$. I don't want something like that to happen.

Comment: The constant $C$ can depend on $\lambda$, but I don't want it to make the term $\lambda^{-p}$ disappear. For example, we can have $C= \lambda^{n}$, so $C\lambda^{-p}$ = $\lambda^{n-p}$, but that $n-p < 0$.

Comment: Then just do as what Iosif said and take the limit as $\lambda \to \infty$. The RHS is bound by $\lambda^{n-p}$ times the $H^1_0$ norm of the function $f$ and so goes to zero, but the LHS doesn't. The kind of result you want is patently impossible.

Comment: I understood. Thanks for the emotions.

Comment: @user253963 : I have added an explicit example showing that your desired bound is impossible.

Comment: Would you get an inequality that way, but instead of $\lambda^{-k}$ being 0? that is, the integrals would be from 0 to 1. Because I'm noticing that what's causing the problem is $\lambda^{-k}$ as one of the integration factors.

Comment: @user253963 : What do you mean by "an inequality" and "that way"? You should strive for clarity, specificity, and precision in what you say -- otherwise, it is hardly possible to understand what you are saying. Give it a good deal of time to reread and rethink well what you want to ask before actually asking. Also, I don't see any problems caused by $\lambda^{-k}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an elementary proof of a related inequality (with non-sharp constants), which may explain what Iosif said in his answer. For ease of typing, instead of $\lambda^{-k}$ I will just type $y \ll 1$.

Let $f$ be a $C^1$ function vanishing at $1$, then you have

$$ \int_y^1 (x f(x)^2)' = - y f(y)^2 $$

Expanding the left you get

$$ \int_y^1 f(x)^2 + 2 \int_y^1 x f(x) f'(x) = - y f(y)^2 $$

rearrange and use Cauchy-Schwarz, you get

$$ \int_y^1 f(x)^2 \leq 2\big(\int_y^1 x^{2-\alpha} f(x)^2\big)^{1/2} \big(\int_y^1 x^\alpha f'(x)^2 \big)^{1/2} + y f(y)^2 $$

Young's inequality makes it, for every $\epsilon > 0$:

$$ \int_y^1 f(x)^2 \leq \epsilon \int_y^1 x^{2-\alpha} f(x)^2 + \frac1{\epsilon}\int_y^1 x^\alpha f'(x)^2 + y f(y)^2 $$

Since $\alpha < 2$, we have $x^{2-\alpha} \leq 1$, so we can absorb

$$ (1-\epsilon) \int_y^1 f(x)^2 \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_y^1 x^\alpha f'(x)^2  + y f(y)^2 $$

To handle the boundary term, you can write

$$ f(y)^2 = \big( \int_y^1 f'(x) \big)^2 \leq (1-y) \int_y^1 f'(x)^2 \leq (1-y) y^{-\alpha} \int_y^1 x^\alpha f'(x)^2 $$

So you get, all things considered

$$ \int_y^1 f^2 \leq \frac{1}{1-\epsilon} \left( \frac{1}{\epsilon} + y^{1-\alpha}(1-y) \right) \int_y^1 x^\alpha (f')^2$$

Choosing $\epsilon = 1/2$ you get

$$ \int_{\lambda^{-k}}^1 f^2 \leq (4 + 2 \lambda^{-(1-\alpha)k}) \int_{\lambda^{-k}}^1 x^\alpha |f'|^2 \leq 6 \int_{\lambda^{-k}}^1 x^\alpha |f'|^2 $$

---

So, to make this look like your original expression, if $C$ is allowed to be a function of $\lambda$, you can choose $C = 6 \lambda^p$ and the desired inequality will hold.

But you cannot recast this inequality in the form of $C\lambda^{-p}$ with a constant $C$ independent of $\lambda$, due to the number $4$ that shows up.

Comment: $C = 6\lambda^{-p}$. the sign of $p$ is negative.

Comment: where does the number 4 appear? Please.

Comment: There is a 4 in $4 + 2 \lambda^{-(1-\alpha)k}$.

Comment: @user253963: if $C = 6 \lambda^p$, then $C \lambda^{-p} = 6$, so the the answer above proves $\int_{\lambda^{-k}}^1 f^2 \leq C \lambda^{-p} \int_{\lambda^{-k}}^1 x^\alpha (f')^2$.

Comment: I understood. Thanks for the emotions.

Comment: I voted his as best answer because he posted it first and I can only select one. But yours I would upvote 10 times if it were possible. Thanks.

Comment: Would you get an inequality that way, but instead of $\lambda^{-k}$ being 0? that is, the integrals would be from 0 to 1. Because I'm noticing that what's causing the problem is $\lambda^{-k}$ as one of the integration factors.

Comment: If $y = 0$, then you don't have the lower boundary $y f(y)^2$ that shows up from the fundamental theorem of calculus (it equals $0$). In this case you get the estimate $\int_0^1 (f)^2 \leq 4 \int_0^1 x^{\alpha} (f')^2$, which is same as what you get by just taking the expression in my answer and taking the limit $y\to 0$.